# where are photos missing files stored

Tags: release-juno, photos

when i delete photos from my photos folder i still can see it in the photos app in the missing files tab i still can delete that but i wondered where is it stored ?

[image]

and if i deleted it from the missing files is it deleted completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably [photos](/questions/tagged/photos) saved the thumbnail for that image but because the image isn't there it says that is missing. That is why [photos](/questions/tagged/photos) can still be able to show you the thumbnail.

Thumbnails:

```
$HOME/.cache/io.elementary.photos/thumbs/
```